# Php pulling false mysql data

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM feeder_categories');

        $result = $query->result();

        $cat = '';

        print $category;

        foreach ($result as $row) {

            $selected = '';

            if($row->Category_Term=$category){$selected = 'selected="1"'; print $row->Category_Term;}

            $cat .= "<option value='" . $row->Category_Term . "' ".$selected.">" . $row->Category_Label .

                "</option>";

        }
```

The database looks like this (According to phpMyAdmin)

```
id  Category_Term   Category_Label
1   Film            Film & Animation
2   Autos           Autos & Vehicles
3   Music           Music
4   Animals         Pets & Animals
5   Sports          Sports
6   Travel          Travel & Events
7   Shortmov        Short Movies
8   Videoblog       Videoblogging
```

Yet the script says that $row->Category_Term is sports every single time it cycles through the list. Its returning $row->Category_Label properly though.

This was working perfectly fine on an Xampp dev server. It was then moved to a nginx vps for release, and this stupid error showed up.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to the category here instead of comparing:

```
if($row->Category_Term=$category)
```

Equality is done in PHP with a double-equals, so change it to:

```
if($row->Category_Term == $category)
```

Comment: And, of course, there's `===` for strict equality/identity, which is generally better.